# Where can I store my config file using windows forms?

Tags: c#, xml, windows, winforms, directory

I'm fairly new to windows forms and I was recently tasked with creating a simple software which will be deployed by USB drives to other companies. I made this software so during first run I check for a config.xml file. If it doesn't exist, I will send the user to a form to configure their first time setup. Next time I run the program, it skips this step since the config.xml file is found with its values. The problem is when I debugged this, I found the config.xml file alongside the executable, however when I ran this on a different computer, it stored it into the appdata virtual store. I read up on this and found out it has to do with write permissions.

Is there any way I can get around this without prompting the user to do anything extra on their part such as run as administrator? I also plan on saving the resulting reports generated by the use of this program and was hoping I can have XML files which can be easily found within the application folder.

*Note, I am aware of the built-in settings system but this also stores into appdata and if the executable is moved to another directly, it loses sight of that config and wants to create another.

**EDIT :** Please be aware I am trying to AVOID writing to the AppData folder. The software is packaged with Visual Studio Installer - Setup Project. A msi file is created which stores the application in C:\Program Files (x86)\\. Inside this directory I have the executable, the exe.config file which is generated, and any DLLs needed. This is the folder I am trying to also store the config.xml file but due to some windows magic, the code thinks its storing it here but in reality it is being stored in the virtualStore folder located in AppData.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write to AppData.

Comment: @SLaks No, please reread the question.

Comment: AppData is per-user and does not require admin and does not involve virtual store.

Comment: But how do you specify the path for your config file when you create it for the first time?. It seems that your code creates it and it chooses the location so it is not clear why it can't retrieve the location.

Comment: @Steve I create the file using StreamWriter just by providing the file name, so this should create it at the root directory. Which is does, but it creates the virtual store copy of the root directory instead of storing it in the true directory where the executable lies. The program can write and read the file no problem. Its just the directory isn't truly where I tell it to be.

Comment: have you tried AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: @AdamHeeg I just tried it. I assume it would do the same as not including it since both methods should return root of the executable. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue due to security concerns that write permissions are limited.
More can be learned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927387/common-file-and-registry-virtualization-issues-in-windows-vista-or-in).

Since no one was able to answer this, I will post my solution. Instead of packaging the solution using Visual Studio Installer tools. I install the application by copying the resulting executable from the build. This version of the application has write permissions that would have not existed if the application was installed using the resulting .msi from the Installer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using the C:\ most computers have this unlocked. alternitively use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`
the AppData folder is stored in the username space and requires no permission. (just remember to create a folder for your program to avoid conflicts)

Comment: I use Visual Studio Installer - Setup Wizard so it automatically creates a folder in the program files for the application. My whole point is to avoid the AppData folder because I will eventually want to store some exported data and I don't want to explain to the users how to access the app data. I will edit my question since it seems like a lot of users are confused.

Comment: Ahh i see. What about a folder in my documents.
Many programs like Visual Studio,Word and Rpg maker use this method to store temp and config files
@AthanasiosKaragiannis